# Molarity 1% ammonia solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry, concentration

I have a stock solution of 25% ammonia, with a density of 910 g/L. I used this to make a 1% ammonia solution by mixing 20 mL 25% ammonia into 480 mL distilled water with 5.84 g NaCl (0.2 M), density ~1000 g/L.

To calculate the molarity of the 25% stock solution, I used the following equation:

Molarity = (Percentage concentration * Density in g/L) / (Molar mass * 100)

Molarity = 13.36 M

To calculate the molarity of the 1% solution, do I need use the density of the 25% solution, or use the new density from the mixed solution?

If I calculate molarity by C1*V1=C2*V2 so that C2 = 13.36 M * 20 mL / 500 mL I get a molarity of 0.5344 M, the same as if i'd used the density of the 25% ammonia in the former calculation. But i'm unsure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Is the percentage w/w, v/v?

Comment: @Zhe i'm unsure. The bottle doesn't mention anything like that, it just says %: https://uk.vwr.com/store/product/2345606/ammonia-solution-25-analar-normapur-analytical-reagent

Comment: It is w/w (unfortunately not often stated).

Comment: w/w is the easiest to deal with. For a fixed mass of solution (easy to compute from the volume and density), you can compute the mass of ammonia and this mass is fixed regardless of the final volume of solution from dilution.